# Create C# WPF DLL who can be used by VB

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, user-interface, dll

I try to create a DLL in C# with the WPF framework. I want to use this DLL in VB (on excel) as GUI. I develop my DLL on Visual Studio and I created a UserControl WPF Library project.

The goal is to create GUI interface in C# DLL with WPF and use it on my Visual Basic script. For exemple: I want to create 2 buttons with WPF/C#, create a DLL who contains my 2 buttons. Then, display them in my Visual Basic Window.

I created a UserControl WPF project and I place 2 buttons in this UserControl.
See my xaml code: [image: Code's Xaml]

My C# class: 
[image]

My DLL build with success.
Then I run this command for register my DLL:

```
regasm /codebase /s WpfControlLibrary1.dll
```

But after these steps, I don't see the reference of my DLL in VB. And I can't create on object of type of WpfControlLibrary1.

So my question is...how create a C# DLL with a GUI WPF who can be display in Visual Basic GUI ?
Should I create a UserControl WPF project in Visual Studio ?
Are there other solutions ?

A simple C# DLL without WPF work fine in VB but i don't how to do with WPF GUI...

Thank's for any helps ;)

Comment: " I can't create on object of type of WpfControlLibrary1". WpfControlLibrary1 is a namespace. it can't have instances

Comment: Yes, but can't also create a UserControl1 object, anyway i can't add the reference to VB

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the UserControlLibrary Project. However, I have faced one similar situation before where I had to work on a project which was already developed in Vb.net. So, we were developing new controls in C# and referencing them in Vb.net.

1. Create a Class library.

[image]

2. Add references: System.xaml, Presentationcore, System.drawing

[image]

3. Add new UserControl item to the solution.

[image]

4. After this stage, you can modify your user control as per your wish. Open new/existing Vb.net Project and add this .dll (created from C#, containing the usercontrol) as reference.
5. Inside Xaml, add reference to the namespace and use the same.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue, which is with creating a UI library that can be used from Excel.